# How can I display which Event strings are available for an object in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I see that in an ide like FlashDevelop, when I add an event listener to certain objects, it'll auto-populate with the event strings that this object will dispatch (I'm assuming, anyway). I'd love to do this with my custom objects (esp. when it comes to sharing this code with co-workers), to clear up possible confusion as to what to listen for.

Does anyone know how to discern which events will be dispatched?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to link suggestions to a method call as strictly as exists with the inbuilt stuff like `addEventListener()`, but that shouldn't stop you from producing perfectly readable code for you and your colleagues (especially if you are using FlashDevelop).

For starters, using your own event class with static properties representing the event strings you can use will provide a useful code hint by default:

[image]

From here, you can add code comments that work with FlashDevelop to produce a very precise tooltip:

[image]

Comment: What about the `[Event]` metadata that you can add to signify that a class dispatches a particular event? I always thought that's how the IDE figured it out... but was always assumin'

Comment: @SunilD. I'm not familiar with the metadata you're referring to - I'd be very interested in any material you can find that makes a reference to it.

Comment: Opps, my bad, I was referring to the [Flex metadata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html) tags! Not sure why I thought they would apply to pure AS3...

Comment: @SunilD. Ahh that's a shame, I would have liked to implement something like that in my game engine.

Comment: @SunilD. They do. Whether or not the data is interpreted depends on the IDE, though. Check Philipp's  answer to this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675402/as3-eventname-type-what-is-the-significance

Comment: thanks for the info, all! that link, weltraumpirat, answered my question! thanks again